# Collision based array index setter doesn't work

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I'm writing a simple android game with java and I want to select on of the joints (with the custom class Joint) based on touches. Here is how I've tried to to it :

```
public int select(Joint[] j){
       int selected = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<j.length;i++){
            if(Rect.intersects(j[i].boxCollider, new Rect(tx,ty,tx+1,ty+2)){
                 selected = i;
                 break;
            }
       }
       return selected;
}
```

the j[i].boxCollider is a Rect object and tx and ty stand for the touchevent coordinates. 
Please help, I've got no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? What is it supposed to do, what does it do instead? What are your inputs? How is `Joint` defined? What is `Rect`?

Comment: At a guess you need a bigger box - something like `new Rect(tx - 5,ty - 5,tx+5,ty+5)`?

Comment: it is supposed to set a global variable to the index of selected (a local variable of the method) . But instead, selected remains zero at all times, like the "for" loop doesn't even happen. Rect is a class of the android sdk that is a rectangle.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon tried it... it doesn't work as well.